# How to get "xy" of a transformed polygon

Tags: python, matplotlib

`poly` is a given polygon.

```
>>> from matplotlib.figure import Figure
>>> import matplotlib as mpl
>>> fig = Figure(figsize=(10, 8))
>>> ax = fig.add_subplot()
>>> ax.add_patch(poly)
>>> poly
<matplotlib.patches.Polygon object at 0x7fbf5f313a90>
>>> poly.xy
array([[ 24.56, -32.63],
       [ 30.36,  -7.01],
       [ 24.56, -32.63]])
>>> t = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().translate(2, 2)
>>> poly.set_transform(t + ax.transData)
>>> poly.xy
array([[ 24.56, -32.63],
       [ 30.36,  -7.01],
       [ 24.56, -32.63]])
>>>
```

The polygon has been transformed, but it does not affect its `xy` attribute.

How can I get the `xy` of the transformed polygon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emilio drive me on the good track. But `poly.get_transform()` seems to be different than the transformation itself.

The correct answer is: `t.transform(poly.xy)`

Comment: Please note that you gave `t + ax.transData` to poly as a transform, so I assumed you wanted that.

Answer (score 2):

```py
poly.get_transform().transform(poly.xy)
```

From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.AffineBase.transform).

Comment: The result of this is not correct. For example [ 24.56, -32.63] is transformed to [776.69899085, 255.52972249].